# Matching the wordss (character) with reference value in R

Tags: r, character, matching

This is a my data (A).

```
    keyword
[1] shoes
[2] childrenshoes
[3] nikeshoes
[4] sportsshiirts
[5] nikeshirts
[6] shirts
...
```

Also, that is another data (B). It is a reference data.

```
   keyword  value
[1] shoes    1
[2] shirts   2
...
```

I need to match this dataset.

So, I want to that results.

```
    keyword        vlaue
[1] shoes          1
[2] childrenshoes  1     (because, this keyword include the 'shoes')
[3] nikeshoes      1     (because, this keyword include the 'shoes')
[4] sportsshiirts  2     (because, this keyword include the 'shirts')
[5] nikeshirts     2     (because, this keyword include the 'shirts')
[6] shirts         2
...
```

If I utilize the 'merge', I colud not match this dataset. This is because keywords in data(B) is not perfectly match with data in data(A).

I can handle this one by one by using regexpr() or gregexpr(). 
However, I have a lot of refernece in data (B)

So, How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Interesting question. Do be sure that in the future, you share your example data in a way that is easy for others on the site to copy-and-paste before experimenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach:

First, your data:

```
temp <- c("shoes", "childrenshoes", "nikeshoes", 
          "sportsshiirts", "nikeshirts", "shirts")

matchme <- structure(list(keyword = c("shoes", "shirts"), value = 1:2), 
                     .Names = c("keyword", "value"), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Second, the output, all in one go:

```
data.frame(
  keyword = temp, 
  value = rowSums(sapply(seq_along(matchme[[1]]), function(x) {
    temp[grepl(matchme[x, 1], temp)] <- matchme[x, 2]
    suppressWarnings(as.numeric(temp))
  }), na.rm = TRUE))
#         keyword value
# 1         shoes     1
# 2 childrenshoes     1
# 3     nikeshoes     1
# 4 sportsshiirts     0
# 5    nikeshirts     2
# 6        shirts     2
```

`grepl` performs logical matching of each element in your "matchme" `data.frame` against your source "temp" `data.frame`. If a match is found, it extracts the value from the "value" column of the "matchme" `data.frame`. Otherwise, it keeps the original value. That's fine, because we know that when we convert the resulting vector using `as.numeric`, anything that can't be coerced to a number will become `NA`.

In the `sapply` step, you'll get a matrix. If we can assume that there will only ever be one match per item, then we can safely use `rowSums` with the argument `na.rm = TRUE` to "collapse" that matrix into a single vector that can be combined with our "temp" data to create the resulting `data.frame`.

I've added a `suppressWarnings` in there because I know that I will get lots of `NAs introduced by coercion` warnings that don't tell me anything I don't already know.

Note the `0` for "sportsshiirts". If you need approximate matching, you might want to look into `agrep` and see if you can modify this approach.